# When should I use 'onto'/'on to' instead of 'on'?

Tags: prepositions

Why is it "move up on TO a platform" but "get up on a bicycle"? My idea was that if there's a movement or a change of state, one should add 'to' to 'in' or 'on'. Lexico seems to have a different idea, though

[image]

Comment: I don't know why they haven't used _to_ in 1.2. It would be perfectly acceptable to do so.

Comment: @katebunting acceptable or mandatory?

Comment: If I had meant that it was mandatory I would have worded my comment differently. _Get up on, get on_ and _get on to_ are all idiomatic.

Comment: @katebunting so I don't need to add 'to' after 'get on', 'jump on', etc. at all, do I? What about 'get in'? Is it mandatory then?

Comment: "Get in the car" - "Get into the car" - both are acceptable. _Into_ and _onto_ convey the idea of movement.

Comment: @katebunting and that conveyance is 100% voluntary, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  In some cases using _on_ could be ambiguous; for instance, to _jump on_ something could mean 'jump up and down on top of it', whereas _jump onto_ can only mean 'reach a position on top of it by jumping.